# Using RNA Property in Drivers?

Tags: python, properties, drivers

I'm currently trying to modify some drivers so that they are disabled when they're not on a proxied armature.  Right now, I'm using the following script to set a custom property, which is used by the drivers:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

class UseHeight(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        ob = context.object
        if("UseHeight" in ob.keys()):
            ob["UseHeight"] = (ob.proxy != None)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UseHeight)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UseHeight)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

However, I have to put this into every script I use, and with how my memory has been impacted by my health problems, I don't want to add yet another thing for me to keep track of.  I've attempted to use it as an addon, but it fails to work due to this error:

```
Exception in module register(): '/home/zauber/.config/blender/2.69/scripts/addons/MaelstromUseHeight.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zauber/Desktop/blender-2.69-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.69/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 311, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "/home/zauber/.config/blender/2.69/scripts/addons/MaelstromUseHeight.py", line 12, in register
    bpy.utils.register_class(UseHeight)
  File "/home/zauber/.config/blender/2.69/scripts/addons/MaelstromUseHeight.py", line 7, in register
    ob = context.object
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'object'
```

So, what do I need to do to get this working?  Or is there a way I can directly check if the object's proxy value is equal to "None" inside the drivers?

Comment: You may not access any bpy.context and bpy.data members (with a few exceptions like for keymaps): [Restricted Context](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Restricted_Context)

Comment: I just spent an hour trying to adapt my code to work around that.  My line count has already doubled or tripled, and nothing works at all.  I've tried stuffing the needed value into a PropertyGroup, but (a) I can't actually get data recorded to it, and (b) it seems that the drivers can't read from the property groups anyways.

Comment: Okay, got it to pull data from the property group by having it's data put into a panel.  However, when I try to change the data by adding the poll function to the panel class, the panel just disappears.  No error output on the console.

Comment: A `poll()` classmethod is supposed to return `True` or `False` to indicate whether the class can be used or not. In case of operater classes, it determines if the context is suitable to invoke/execute the operator. In case of panels, if they shall show. `def poll(cls, context): return context.mode == 'OBJECT'` (only show panel when in object mode)

Comment: Okay, so if it's not something that is meant to be used, what should I be using?  I'm assuming that Operator classes are executed on invocation.  I'm looking for something that just runs automatically.

Comment: You can circumvent the context restriction at registration time by using an app handler, that removes itself (`scene_update_pre`), but this seems all wrong... I tried to add a property function to the driver namespace, but it doesn't work. An exp var did not work either, although I registered a prop on Object type (but showed red as unrecgnized property...)

Comment: Trying to use an app handler with scene_update_pre, as you suggested.  However, I don't know how to make it operate on my objects.  It doesn't seem to have any context field I can plug in, and right now I can only access the currently-selected object, when what I want to do is access armatures.  Also, it appears to be running continuously, several times a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the advice of CoDEmanX and reading documentation, I figured out what to do last night.  I changed it all to use a pair of handler functions.  Here is the altered script:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

bl_info = {
    "name": "Maelstrom Height Handler",
    "category": "Object",
}

'''
Called when the scene is updated, and calls height_general_update if
any objects in the scene have been updated.
'''
@persistent
def height_scene_update(scene):
    if(bpy.data.objects.is_updated):
        height_general_update(scene)

'''
Iterates through each scene object to see if the "height" property
is present, then adds and/or adjusts the "useHeight" property.  Does
nothing if the height is unchanged, to prevent other potential code
from running.  Runs when a scene is loaded or when called by the
above function.
'''
@persistent
def height_general_update(scene):
    didChange = False
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        rigChanged = False
        if("height" in obj.keys()):
            val = int(obj.proxy != None)
            if("useHeight" not in obj.keys()):
                obj["useHeight"] = val
                rigChanged = True
            else:
                if(obj["useHeight"] != val):
                    obj["useHeight"] = val
                    rigChanged = True
        if(rigChanged):
            print("Adjusting useHeight flag of", obj.name)
            didChange = True

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(height_scene_update)
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(height_general_update)

def unregister():
    for idx, val in enumerate(bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre):
        if(val == height_scene_update):
            del bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre[idx]
    for idx, val in enumerate(bpy.app.handlers.load_post):
        if(val == height_general_update):
            del bpy.app.handlers.load_post[idx]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```